# Get a .txt from the Internet, compare it and open a dialog in an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I want to check, if there is an update for my app. For this I put up an txt file online with just an integer of the latest app version. This should get compared with the running app version and when there is a newer version, open a dialog for the user to give the choice of open a link to the new .apk in the browser or to cancel it. It's giving me trouble and I don't know what to do. Thanks for helping me out!

The AsyncTask:

```
public class UpdateCheck extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String str = null;
        try {
            // Create a URL for the desired page
            URL url = new URL("http://googledrive.com/host/0B62qO_dIVN_hQ2lGNmJudDFEdHc/ver.txt");

            // Read all the text returned by the server
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        PackageInfo packageInfo;
        int curVersionCode = 0;
        try {
            packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("de.grevius.hhgvertretungsplan", 0);
            curVersionCode = packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Automatisch generierter Erfassungsblock
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (Integer.parseInt(str) > curVersionCode) {
            return true;

        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute (Boolean bool){
        if(bool){

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            // Add the buttons
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://googledrive.com/host/0B62qO_dIVN_hQ2lGNmJudDFEdHc/Vertretungsplan.apk"));
                           startActivity(intent); //activity.startIntent...
                       }
                   });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
            // Set other dialog properties
            builder.setMessage("Es ist eine neue Version der App verfügbar. Herunterladen?");

            // Create the AlertDialog
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the Log Cat:

```
 12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:355)
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at de.grevius.hhgvertretungsplan.MainActivity$UpdateCheck.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:204)
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at de.grevius.hhgvertretungsplan.MainActivity$UpdateCheck.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-09 17:10:37.305: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    ... 5 more
```

---

I just added some Log-Tags to the code and saw, that it is working until the `Integer.parseInt(str)`. At this time `str` is `<html>`, I don't know where this comes from, because when I look up the source code of my "page" it says just the number...`

I solved it by changing the `while` loop to `while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) { sb.append(str); }` and `Integer.parseInt(sb.toString())`.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's giving me trouble?" Does it throw an Exception? Does it not do anything? What have you done to debug it?

Comment: You should use `SharedPreferences` to do this

Comment: I added the LogCat... I don't know why it isn't working as intendet, I rea through the docmentaion and everything but don't get it.

I am using SharedPrefernces, but for what u mean directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str` is `null`. Your while loop is incorrect. You keep looping UNTIL it's `null`, thus guaranteeing a null value when you do `Integer.parseInt(str)`

You need to store the last valid non-null String for use later in parsing the int.

Comment: I removed the while and just put `str = in.readLine();` there, but it still gives an FATAL EXCEPTION...